# Populate cell with a filename based on path excerpt in previous cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with an excel spreadsheet that has a list of titles in column A, and a list of filenames in column D. The filenames are created with a specific naming convention that's based on the title in column A-- for example, if the title in A1 is "Taco_123," then the filename in D1 will contain the exact phrase "Taco_123".

At the moment, the filenames must be entered manually into D1 after the files have been created. But what I'd like is a VBA script that would do that automatically. My idea is that for each row it would read the title in column A, search for the file containing that exact phrase in the directory where the files are, then copy the file name (minus the extension) into column D.

Is such a thing even possible? I've tried searching for a solution online as I know zilch about VBA, but I haven't had much luck; I can't even find someone else with the same problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but the filetype that would need to be searched for a matching file name is PSD.

Comment: What have you tried? And what version of Excel? One approach would be to pull all the file names  with the matching extension into an array then run through each one matching it to the right row in your column D. How to get the names of file names in a folder depends on the version of Excel though.

Comment: @JamieBull It's excel 2010.

Comment: you will have to use or modify the solution from P. Havdra, here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a450830d-4fc3-4f4e-aee2-03f7994369d6/

Comment: What if Col A has for example `Monthly_Report` and you have 2 files in the directory which are named as `Jan_Monthly_Report` and `Feb_Monthly_Report`

Comment: @SiddharthRout In this case, that will never happen. The titles in Col A are very specific-- for example, "Taco_123_1", "Taco_123_2", and so on. The script will (well, should) always find a file with that exact title in it.

Comment: @ajw-art: SO what my understanding is that Col A has the exact files names which needs to be checked if they are in a particular directory and if they are then you need that in Col B?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The titles in Column A (Taco_123_1, for example) are included somewhere in the filenames (xyz_Taco_123_1_abc.psd, for example). What I'd like is for the script to check every filename for "_Taco_123_1_" (or whatever the title in column A is) and output the matching filename, minus the extension, into Column D of the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing is definitely possible. There was an easy way to do this in older versions of excel using Application.FileSearch in like, Excel 2003 and prior. For 2007 and newer, you will have to use or modify the solution from P. Havdra, here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a450830d-4fc3-4f4e-aee2-03f7994369d6/

This script prints out a list of files matching your search parameters and also gives you an annoying message box popup.

I made some modifications to his FileSearch subroutine to get you started. This builds an array of matching PSD file names in a specified directory and then you can do stuff with the array and interact with your worksheet data.

```
Sub FileSearch()
'
' Example of FileSearchByHavrda procedure calling as replacement of missing FileSearch     function in the newest MS Office VBA
' 01.06.2009, Author: P. Havrda, Czech Republic

'As modified Feb-13-2013, David Zemens, for _
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865258/populate-cell-with-a-filename-based-on-path-excerpt-in-previous-cell
'
Dim sDir As String  '< this is the search directory you will use

Dim FileNameWithPath As Variant
Dim ListOfFilenamesWithParh As New Collection ' create a collection of filenames
Dim rCount As Long 'row counter

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim a As Long 'array iterator
a = 0

'Set the search directory:
sDir = "C:\DESKTOP\"  '<-- MODIFY TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS

' Filling a collection of filenames (search Excel files including subdirectories)
Call FileSearchByHavrda(ListOfFilenamesWithParh, sDir, "*.psd", False)

' Print list to immediate debug window and as a message window
For Each FileNameWithPath In ListOfFilenamesWithParh ' cycle for list(collection) processing
    'Create an array of matching filenames
    ReDim Preserve myArray(a)
    myArray(a) = FileNameWithPath
    a = a + 1
Next FileNameWithPath

' If no file was found:
If ListOfFilenamesWithParh.Count = 0 Then
    'Debug.Print "No file was found !"
    MsgBox "No file was found !"
Else:
    'some files were found, so do something with myArray
    '########################################################
    '
    '  <-- Code to manipulate your worksheet will go here -->
    '
    '
    '########################################################
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. So what so I do with the data in the array? Does Excel just know automatically to output the filenames to the corresponding rows/columns?

Comment: All this code does is build you a 1-dimensional array of PSD filenames in the directory specified by the `sDir` variable. What you do with the array (which is basically a **list** of filenames including the file paths) is up to you. You will need to identify matches and probably need to use some string functions (`InStr` and `Replace` come to mind as useful in this endeavor) to this end, and then print out the desired result (the file path/directory location) to the worksheet in column D.